# WinRAR при вызове из командной строки выдает "отказано в доступе"

Tags: cmd, архивация, rar, winrar

Суть в чем: имеется папка с данными, распиханными в подпапки n-ой степени вложенности. Написала на C# скриптик, который рекурсивно все это дело обходит и упаковывает в архивы с помощью WinRAR (вернее его консольной версии rar.exe) и столкнулась со следующей проблемой: из примерно 3500 архивов около 1500 выдали ошибку доступа при формировании. Пробовала из cmd заархивировать - та же проблема. Пробовала вызывать WinRAR.exe - та же проблема. НО! Если эти же папки архивировать ручками через контекстное меню - все отрабатывает без каких-либо чихов. Отсюда вопрос: WTF? Почему из командной строки не работает, а из контекстного меню работает?

Пример команды для архивации:
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\RAR.exe" A -df -m5 -ep -u -IBCK "C:\DataArchive\2019\январь\01" "C:\DataArchive\2019\январь\01"

Причем ошибка может возникать и не возникать в пределах одной папки, куда файлы грузились в свое время пачкой.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить командную строку из-под админа.

Comment: К сожалению, нет такой возможности - запрещено групповой политикой((( Это первое, что пришло мне в голову, но не получится. Я пытаюсь понять почему одни папки архивируются без проблем, а соседние - "ошибка доступа". Да и ручками то я архивирую не от имени админа((